# Rails loop, link_to model_view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails: Need help looping through model array to link to the show page. I want to show the name, but link to the path. Seems like it should be simple but I have been coding all night and my brain is fried! please help.

```
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
           <% @bars.each do |bar| %>
            <div class="col-xs-6 something">
              <div class="firstBar">
                <%= link_to bars_path %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try `<%= link_to bar.name, bar %>`

Comment: simple and effective, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% @bars.each do |bar| %>
      <div class="col-xs-6 something">
        <div class="firstBar">
          <%= link_to bar.name, bar %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also do `<%= link_to bar.name, bars_path(bar) %>`, but is prettier to just give the object. Rails will know which Url helper to use given a specific object.

Take a look at the [UrlHelper documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% @bars.each do |bar| %>
      <div class="col-xs-6 something">
        <div class="firstBar">
        <%= link_to bar.name, bar_path(bar) %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```